# Downloading ArcGIS Online Feature Service to local Geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-hub

I want to grab some feature services from ArcGIS Hub and put them on a GDB on my local PC. Here's the code that I've got so far:

```
import arcpy

# Set project directory
proj_dir = 'C:\\Users\\rhard2\\Documents\\am_ml_mainlines_v_01'

# Grab online data (feature services):
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS()

# Connect to AGOL
LA_geological_faults = gis.content.get(('4bb7809eac534689b36b2d347ac96220'))
LA_streets_cl = gis.content.get(('d3cd48afaacd4913b923fd98c6591276'))
LA_streets_width = gis.content.get(('13c2f36f37894faa8ecc918b29f9b156'))

# Return items (feature services) above:
display(LA_geological_faults, LA_streets_cl, LA_streets_width)

# Set out location for the containers
container_1_gdb = os.path.join(proj_dir,'container_1.gdb')

# Place them to container_1.gdb
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features=LA_geological_faults, out_path=container_1_gdb, out_name='LA_geological_faults', config_keyword="")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features=LA_streets_cl, out_path=container_1_gdb, out_name='LA_streets_cl', config_keyword="")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features=LA_streets_width, out_path=container_1_gdb, out_name='LA_streets_width', config_keyword="")
```

But this gave me an error:

> RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

Questions: 
I read somewhere (I couldn't find the link) that FeatureClasstToFeatureClass is supposed to support feature service. What have I done wrong? How do I download a feature service layer and put them into a GDB in my computer?

I use ArcGIS Pro 2.4

Comment: Can you add an error handler to your code, rerun the code, and include the new error message?  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/error-handling-with-python.htm

Comment: I'm flagging this as a duplicate because you're using the ArcGIS Python API in addition to ArcPy. The duplicate question shows how you need to pass the URL of the feature service into the tool, _not_ the ArcGIS Python API Item reference.